# How to prove that there is no positive integer solution to this two variables inequalities system?

Tags: inequality

I would like to know if it is possible to prove that there are no integer solutions to:
$$
\begin{cases}
77n &- 154m &\leq -1\\
154m &- 77n &\leq 76
\end{cases}
$$
I have no idea how to start, so any comments are welcome.
Thank you and regards, Tony.

Comment: Use that $154$ is divisible by $77$.

Comment: yes, i need to prove that there are no integer solutions for n and m.

Comment: What is a number of natural numbers on $[1,76]$, which are divisible by $77$?

Comment: how about 154y - 154x <= -1 and 154m - 154m <=76? how to find x and integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given inequalities can be written as $$1\le 154m-77n\le 76\;\;,where\,m,n\in N$$
$$0\lt\frac{1}{77}\le 2m-n\le \frac{76}{77}\lt 1$$
$$\forall m,n \in N \;\;,2m-n\in I $$
For any positive integer $m,n\;\;, 2m-n\notin (0,1)$ $$. $$
Hence therefore there doesnot exist any positive integer $m,n$ that satisfy both inequality.

Comment: Where can I learn about the theorem or proof that you gave me, Rajan?

Comment: These all are part of school level mathematics for which one more site which I follow is. https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/. You can find some and also learn there.

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality gives $n-2m \le -\frac{1}{77}.$ Since $n-2m$ is an integer, we get

$(1) \quad n-2m \le -1.$

The second inequality gives $2m-n \le \frac{76}{77}.$ Since $2m-n$ is an integer, we get

$(2) \quad 2m-n \le 0.$

But from $(1)$ it follows that $2m-n \ge 1.$ This is a contradiction to $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Fred. Are there any references for the theorem that I can read to prove the contradiction?